# Find values of the constants in the following identity: x^4+Ax^3 + 5x^2 + x + 3 = (x^2+4)(x^2-x+B)+Cx+ D

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Another question on identities:

$$x^4+Ax^3 + 5x^2 + x + 3 = (x^2+4)(x^2-x+B)+Cx+ D$$

How can I find the coefficients for this?

I've got as far as multiplying out the brackets to get:

$$x^4+Ax^3 + 5x^2 + x + 3 = (x^4-x^3+Bx^2+4x^2-4x+4B)+Cx+ D$$

It would be useful to get a hint at least on where to go next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost to the final solution. Just combine all coefficients of various powers or $x$ and compare each of them individually:

$$
x^4+Ax^3 + 5x^2 + x + 3 = x^4-x^3+ (B+4)x^2+(C-4)x+4B+ D
$$
You'll get

$$
\begin{align}
A &= -1 \\
B &= +5 - 4 \\
&= 1 \\
C &= +1 +4 \\
&= 5 \\
D &= 3 - 4B \\
&= -1
\end{align}
$$

---

#### Edit

To explain a little as [OP mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417678/find-values-of-the-constants-in-the-following-identity-x4ax3-5x2-x-3/417689#comment893566_417689):

The process is as simple as taking everything onto one side of **$=$**:

$$
(x^4 - x^4) + (A x^3 + x^3) + (5 x^2 - (B + 4) x^2 ) + (x - (C - 4)x ) + \left(3 - (4B + D)\right) = 0 \\
\implies (A + 1) x^3 + (1 - B) x^2 + (4 - C) x + (3 - 4B - D) = 0 \\
\therefore \pmatrix{ A + 1 \\ 1 - B \\ 4 - C \\ 3 - 4B - D } = \pmatrix{ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 }
$$
which gives you the result.

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu Thanks. I used the exponent :/ I should sleep now.

Comment: You are welcome...

Comment: does this mean you should simplify further by removing x^4 from the rhs and lhs?, divide both sides by x ?

Comment: I'm missing some steps or intuition on how exactly you compare. can you please explain

Comment: @peter_gent Okay, check the edit to my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can equate the coefficients of each power of $x$ from both sides.

Like you equate the coefficient of $x^3$ to get $A=-1$